# Merge dataset information same cell

Tags: r, merge

I need to do a dataset merge but the information is in the same cell, how can I do it?

```
dati1<- c("a - Novara", "b - Torino", "c - Milano", "f - Bari")

dati2<- c("a", "b", "c", "f")

dat3 <- dati1<- c("Novara", "Torino", "Milano", "Bari")

result

tot <- data.frame(dati2, dat3)
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: use `strsplit()` on dati1 ?

Comment: I would like have tot
data1 isn't a string, it works?

Comment: @Maël 's solution is more accurate because calling `cbind()` and then doing the transpose `t()` is a bit pointless when you have `rbind()` . I'll delete my reply. You should accept the other answer as the right one for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dati1, split = " - ")))

  X1     X2
1  a Novara
2  b Torino
3  c Milano
4  f   Bari
```

or with `tidyr::separate`:

```r
separate(data.frame(dati1), col = dati1, into = str_c("col", 1:2))
```

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(dati1) %>% 
  mutate(dati1= str_split_fixed(dati1, '\\-', 2), .keep="unused")
```

```
  dati1.1 dati1.2
1      a   Novara
2      b   Torino
3      c   Milano
4      f     Bari
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option

```
read.table(text = dati1, header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, sep = "-")
  V1     V2
1  a Novara
2  b Torino
3  c Milano
4  f   Bari
```